# querying data from client using signalR

Tags: c#, signalr

We are planning to use signalR in place of wcf dual communication, since the latter has firewall issues because of port

Everything works great so far, i am able to

1. subscribe to hub event from proxy `proxy.On<Type>()`
2. send data to clients using `Clients.MethodName(arg1, arg2)`

but iam not able to figure out if its possible for hub to query data from client.

---

please see dfowlwer's comment above, doesnt look like this is possible

Comment: What do you mean "query data from the client"?

Comment: for example is it possible for the hub to call a method on client and get data back

Comment: You want to call a method on the client from the server and get data back from the client? No that's not possible with SignalR. The client can call the server though. See the .NET client documentation https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs

Comment: I think this question is not too localized at all. I would like to do exactly this. Consider an example: a large chain of small companies that has an on premise server on each locations local network that talks to their cloud services. I'm assuming now you can think of many advantages in many scenarios. I leave this single example very general to illustrate how not localized this question is. 507 views in 2 years isn't bad either and seems to suggest the same. I have an idea for a work around but I would've liked to have seen what other people with more experience with SignalR suggest.